# Creating a FactoryBot Hash model with complicated structure, including multiple nested attributes

Tags: ruby, hash, factory-bot

I'm implementing a set of Cucumber driven API tests and stumbled into one specific model that has a few nested elements, like this:

```
factory :human_being, class: Hash do
  human {
    name {
      first_name { Faker::Name.first_name }
      last_name  { Faker::Name.last_name }
    } 
    age { rand(1..100) }
  }
  initialize_with { attributes }
end
```

The result I wanted to achieve should look like this:

```
{   
  :human => {
    :name => {
      :first_name => "mike",
      :last_name => "blob"
      },
    :age => 16    
  }
}
```

I am invoking creation using FactoryBot.build(:human_being) and I get `undefined method 'name' for #<FactoryBot::SyntaxRunner:0x00007fd640a39a80>`

My env.rb has the `World(FactoryBot::Syntax::Methods)` / `FactoryBot.find_definitions` lines.

I've lurked through a few answers regarding the nested attributes / associations / traits but I didn't find a proper way to get what I want. Sorry if the post is duplicated and thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, seems that I've found the solution right after posting the question. Currently the following model creates the Hash I described in the question:

```
factory :human_being, class: Hash do
  human { {
    name: {
      first_name: Faker::Name.first_name,
      last_name:  Faker::Name.last_name,
    },
    age: rand(1..100),
    sex: %w(male female other).sample
  } }
  initialize_with { attributes }
end
```

Although I'm not sure it is a completely correct answer from guidelines perspective, but at least it works for my exact case.

[source](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/factory_bot/file/GETTING_STARTED.md#Associations) (See 'Defining factories'): Because of the block syntax in Ruby, defining attributes as Hashes (for serialized/JSON columns, for example) requires two sets of curly brackets:

```
factory :program do
  configuration { { auto_resolve: false, auto_define: true } }
end
```

Comment: you don't need to set `initialize_with { attributes }`, that is already the default